# Structuring MySQL table (infinite amount columns)

Tags: php, mysql

like title says, I'm wondering how you can structure a mySQL table to be able to add infinite (or high, ≈1000) amount columns.

Basically, I want a table containing column with school classes. Each class has some students in it with their name and last name. The structure I want it something like this:

```
-----Class 1-----------
Lastname-Surname
1. Michel Ericsson
2. Erica  Bloom
....
-----Class 2-----------
Lastname-Surname
1. Fred Jackson
2. Erica Hancock
....

......
```

Comment: Do not do this. See normalization.

Comment: This table will make you very unhappy.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is create a Many to Many relation between a "Class" table and your "Student" table. For example you have a table

```
Class
    id: int (primary key auto-incremented)
    name: varchar
```

And another table :

```
Student
    id: int (primary key auto-incremented)
    name: varchar
    surname: varchar
```

And then, you need a table that will be the link between these previous two :

```
Class_student
    class_id: int (primary key)
    student_id: int (primary key)
```

This way you can link as many Students to as many classes you want.

Comment: And now when I think about it, wouldn't it be easier just making a table with three columns; surname, lastname and classname.  Then when I want to retrieve all students from a certain class I select all with the class name "A" for example. Or is this possible?

Comment: With this you lose the ability for a student to have multiple classes. Your relation becomes a Many to One (Many being the students) and One being the class